# Inconsistent behavior of : operator

Tags: r

I was trying to create a sequence of odd values using the `:` operator (like in Octave), when I ran into a weird behavior.

I tried the same operation with different values.

```
> 1:2:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
Warning message:
In 1:2:10 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
> 1:0.2:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> 1:0.5:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> 1:0.9:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> 1:1.9:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> 1:2.9:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
Warning message:
In 1:2.9:10 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
> 1:3.9:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
Warning message:
In 1:3.9:10 : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

I don't understand the difference. I would like to know why sometimes I get a warning and other times not and the difference in warning messages. I know I have to use `seq` to get the odd values I wanted, but this inconsistent behavior puzzles me.

Comment: as showed, the expression is wrong.  You may need `seq`  Please show your expected output

Comment: I know the expression is wrong. But why there is a warning sometimes and not others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
1:1.9
```

the result is

```
# 1
```

and so `1:1.9:10` is the same as `1:10`.

But when you call

```
1:2
```

you get

```
# 1 2
```

Hence `1:2:10` is the same as calling

```
c(1, 2):10 # which gives 1:10 see warning
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#Warning message:
#In c(1, 2):10 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

From the help page:

> **Arguments**
>
> from : starting value of sequence.
>
> to : (maximal) end value of the sequence.
>
> ...
>
> Value *to* will be included if it differs from *from* by an integer up to a numeric fuzz of about 1e-7.